# embed a pdf archive like it were part of the html code

Tags: html, pdf, embedding

i had a little question, i want to embed a pdf like it were part of the website, i could rewrite the pdf in html but it will be a lot of work, what would be the best looking option to embed it? 
The pdf has pictures and letters with fonts and columns.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with one of the two approaches. One is a native rendering of the PDF content in a DOM node, using PDF.js. It is an open source library that's used as the default PDF viewer in Firefox.

Another way is to emulate the look by converting the PDF pages to images when the PDF is uploaded. You may use imagemagick to parse the pages, and display the content in a slideshow/gallery widget.

Comment: thank you, the best looking to me was the second one, convert the pdf to jpg